# Requests / Instagram: Can't like a post / follow (POST - 302)

Tags: python-requests, instagram

everyone.
I try to build a bot (requests only) for Instagram. Now I can login, but I can't like a post. Here is code:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json , pickle
from datetime import datetime
import os
from time import sleep
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
link = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
login_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'
proxies = {
    'socks': '104.248.63.17:30588'
}
time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())
jar1, jar2 = "",""
payload = {
    'username': '',
    'enc_password': f'#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:',
    'queryParams': {},
    'optIntoOneTap': 'false'
}

with requests.Session() as s:

    if os.path.isfile("cookies.txt"):
        print("1")
        with open("cookies.txt", 'r') as f:
            # cookies = pickle.load(f)
            # jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
            # jar._cookies = cookies
            # s.cookies = jar
            s.cookies = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(json.load(f))

        jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
        jar.set('tasty_cookie', 'yum', domain='httpbin.org', path='/cookies')
        jar1 = jar

        r = s.get(link, cookies=jar, verify=False)
        sleep(1)
        r = s.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        # with open("cookies2.txt", 'wb') as f:
        #   f.truncate()
        #   print(r.cookies._cookies)
        #   pickle.dump(r.cookies._cookies, f)
        #   #json.dump(requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(r.cookies), f)
        
        # sleep(1)
        # print(jar2)

    else:
        print("2")
        r = s.get(link,verify=False)
        sleep(2)
        csrf = re.findall(r"csrf_token\":\"(.*?)\"", r.text)[0]
        r = s.post(login_url, data=payload, headers={
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "Referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/",
            "x-csrftoken": csrf
        },verify=False)

        print(r.status_code, r.cookies)
        with open("cookies.txt", 'w') as f:
            # f.truncate()
            # pickle.dump(r.cookies._cookies, f)
            json.dump(requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(r.cookies), f)

    sleep(1)

    with open("cookies.txt", 'r') as f:
        # cookies = pickle.load(f)
        # jar2 = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
        # print(cookies)
        # jar2._cookies = cookies
        # s.cookies = jar2
        s.cookies = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(json.load(f))

    jar2 = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
    jar2.set('tasty_cookie', 'yum', domain='httpbin.org', path='/cookies')
        
    sleep(2)
    # r = s.post("https://www.instagram.com/web/likes/3447/like/",cookies=jar2,headers={
    #       "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36",
    #       "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    #       "Referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/"
    #   }, verify=False) 
    # print(r.cookies)
    r = s.get("https://www.instagram.com/baklanskaiav/?__a=1")
    sleep(1)
    print(r)
    r = s.post("https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/39164422021/follow/")
    print(r)
```

It seems, that Instagram thinks, that I am not a logined user.

[image]
[image]

306 bytes is when I follow by myself.
Other is by my script.
I can't manage to send exact the same cookies, when I follow by myself.
Thank you.